# User Branch Interface in Php

Tags: php

This is my scenario and wanted to hear some other thoughts or recommendations.

So i have 2 users Branch Registrar and Branch Principal.
So what i am thinking is for example I'm a registrar of branch a i should only manipulate data of branch a and view data of branch a. This goes for Branch b and c also with Principal user.

What would be a good way to perform/do this. So far my idea is now i have  pages that are mixed from the 3 branches. Lets say Total pages i have now is 3 my planed course of action is to copy those 3 and create 3 pages exactly for each branch making a total of 9. and it will be such a nuisance to create many replicas of pages. Would appreciate any methods on how should i do this task efficiently and quicker. New with this and hope you guys understand.

EDIT: I am using php and mysql(not mysqli for the moment because i want to master mysql first)
   In my database i have the field "Branchname" so i might be able to use that. What i am searching for is a efficient way that the page would know if the user is on a specific branch. would Session suffice?

```
   $_SESSION['branch'] = $get->Branchname;
```

Comment: I have no clue what you are talking about. Add more context please. Apart from that, this question is likely to get closed because there is no obvious concrete programming problem here.

Comment: Using outdated API will not teach you how to work with DB faster. It will only teach you how to do t wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using a database, you may add an authorization field in your table for your registrars and principals, which shall contain the primary key value for the branch which they can manipulate. So when you show data, or allow to modify it, your selection criteria is based on the authorization field.

If you could specify what technology you are using, and some code, maybe I can explain better.

Comment: You could use sessions variable to store the id for your user. Then you can check if the user is authorized to view at each and every page.

If you allow multiple pages to users, you could use a numeric string for the authorization code.Eg: 110 for A and B, 101 for A and C etc.

Comment: Okay. So instead of creating multiple ill just use the Session. Thanks